# How can i manage two different Layouts using useRoutes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is my useRoute code below. All I want is if I go to revenue page... it is working fine but when I go to `"http://localhost:3000/revenue/send-offer-letter"` then browser shows blank screen. How can I use this?

const MainRoutes = [
{
path: "/",
element: ,
children: [
{
path: "/",
element: ,
},
{
path: "/schedule",
element: ,
},
],
},

{
path: "revenue",
element: ,
children: [
{
path: "",
element: ,
},
{
path: "send-offer-letter",
element: ,
},
],
},
];

```
I want nested routing with two different layout screens.

@Drew here is my updated code as your answer 

import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const MainLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here!
  );
};

const RevenueLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here!
  );
};

const MainRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    children: [
      {
        element: <MainLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: (
              <>
                <h1>Main Layout First Page</h1>
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            path: "/schedule",
            element: (
              <>
                <h1>Main Layout Second Page</h1>
              </>
            ),
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: "/revenue",
        element: <RevenueLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: (
              <>
                <h1>Revenue First Page</h1>
              </>
            ),
          },
          {
            path: "send-offer-letter",
            element: (
              <>
                <h1>Revenue Second Page</h1>
              </>
            ),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MainLayout` and `RevenueLayout` routes ***necessarily*** should render an `Outlet` component for the nested children routes to render their `element` content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const MainLayout = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here!
    ...
  );
};

const RevenueLayout = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here!
    ...
  );
};
```

Refactor the routes so `"/revenue"` is a child route of the root `"/"` route.

```
const mainRoutes = [
  {
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: "/schedule",
        element: <ExpenseManagement />
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "revenue",
    element: <RevenueLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <SendOfferLetter />
      },
      {
        path: "send-offer-letter",
        element: <ApplicantList />
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-can-i-manage-two-different-layouts-using-useroutes-in-react]

Comment: if I'm routing to "http://localhost:3000/revenue" then it's working fine but it's not working with this "http://localhost:3000/revenue/send-offer-letter", and i.e., what my query is!!

Comment: above I have added updated code according to your answer

Comment: @manindersingh Can you clarify what *exactly* isn't working? Have you tried the solution I suggest in my answer? I tested this in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-manage-two-different-layouts-using-useroutes-in-react-7wxsp0?file=/src/App.js) and the routing works as I'd expect it to. Feel free to fork that sandbox and add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue from your end. I'm more than happy to take a look/inspect.

Comment: Yes this is working on my system as well but only when I'm using <Link></Link> but I don't want navigation with Link I want to navigate on Button click like this   const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onClickSignIn = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", "dfdfdfdfdf");
    navigate("/revenue/send-offer-letter");
  };

Comment: @manindersingh Links and buttons don't change how routing works. I have updated the demo to use buttons and `navigate` function and it all still works as expected. Can you take another look in the sandbox?

Comment: I have created login form and when I click  on login button then i use Navigate to navigate to particular page... This is working only if I declare <Link ></Link> if i comment  that All Link tags then it is not navigating

Comment: if possible can you comment out all Links then try to navigate by clicking on Button

Comment: @manindersingh You could just as easily try that in the sandbox and verify for yourself. In any case, yes, I commented out the links in the sandbox and the button navigations work just the same.

Comment: @manindersingh See if you can fork my sandbox and copy in more of your actual code so we can see what you are really working with.